# Looking for samples to multiple API calls in python

Tags: python, pandas, api

I am new and learning python. As part of my learning, i am trying to do Api integration. I am getting the result but it's limited to 100. But the totalresults is around 7000 records. Is there a way I can call multiple times to bring the entire result in CSV format. I am adding my code below and not sure how to proceed further.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
resp = requests.get ('apipath' & '?company=XXXX', auth=(XXXXX', 'XXXXXX'))
dataframe = resp.json()
dataset = pd.DataFrame(dataframe["items"]).to_csv('dict_file.csv', header=True)
```

Please help.

Comment: Most APIs that are limited in this way have a `page` or `start` or similar parameter you can pass to get the rest 100 records. The ones that don't have that, there's generally no way to do it (or there is, but it requires finding a way to break up your query itself into 70 or more separate queries that each only get 100 records but together cover the full 7000, but that's usually either not possible or complicated with most APIs).

Comment: Without knowing the exact api you are hitting, no idea. However you can generally send a header or parameter as part of the url, or post body to set the max. number of results returned (in most cases).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check the API Documentation but generally there will be a parameter "maxResults (or similar) that you can add to the url to retrieve more than the default number of results.

Your request (by modify the query string in the url) would look something like this:

```
resp = requests.get ('apipath' & '?company=XXXX&maxResults=1000', auth=(XXXXX', 'XXXXXX'))
```